# Shell script chosing multiple repeats or exit

Tags: linux, shell, select, terminal, case

i have this code:

```
echo "Select"
select yn in "YES" "NO"; do
case $yn in
YES ) break;;
NO ) exit;;
esac
done
```

what im trying to do,is ask the user someting (`select`) and if the user types YES then does what YES does (`break`) and if the user types NO then it does what NO does (`exit`)
how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want the menu to repeat multiple times, remove the break so it will loop, if you want the user to be able to type a literal YES instead of number 1 and have it execute, you need to catch REPLY and take that into account.

SO... to bring these two together, try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
repeat() {
        echo "Repeating";
}
end() {
        echo "Exit";
        exit;
}
echo "Select"
select yn in "YES" "NO"; do
        if [[ -z "$yn" ]]; then
                # user entered text instead of the number
                yn="$REPLY"
        fi
        case $yn in
                YES )
                repeat
                ;;
                NO )
                end
                ;;
                * )
                echo -e "Sorry, \"${yn}\" is not supported.\nTry again."
                ;;
        esac
done
```

Comment: I tried and it says:
Select
proba1.sh: 10: proba1.sh: select: not found
proba1.sh: 11: proba1.sh: [[: not found
-e Sorry, "" is not supported.
Try again.
proba1.sh: 26: proba1.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected

Comment: Weird, what version of bash are you running? I copy pasted it into a script on a bsd and a linux and it just worked.. 
maybe something is weird with the newlines there, try getting it from http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=k4vgm6Hs there, the select on line 10 is the same one from your script.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Which was the problem you were trying to fix? that it repeats or that you can enter text?

Comment: This was how I tested it btw, not sure if your method is different: 
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sq5jNEpx

Comment: OK,so i tested it,and it turned out,it works with the `bash` command,and doesn't with the `sh` command.

Comment: Oh right, yeah sh doesn't have [[, only [. DOH! should've guessed that, glad it works =) thanks for the rep points ;)